# Find the critical points of this two variable function

Tags: calculus, functions

Find the critical points of this  two variable function: $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-4y^3+x^2-33x$

I have this for the partial derivatives in $x$ and $y$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=3x^2+3y^2+2x-33$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=6xy-12y^2=6y(x-2y)$

Thank you.

Comment: Why is (0,0)  a critical point?

Comment: (0,0) is not a critical point of that function.

Comment: I guess i made a mistake

Comment: Show us your work? Maybe there is an conceptual error. For a point to be critical either both partial derivative must be zero or they don't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systems of nonlinear equations can be hard to solve.  You can use cases.

You have two equations, which must both be satisfied.
\begin{align}
3x^2 + 3y^2 + 2x-33 = 0 \tag{1} \\
6xy - 12y^2 = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
Factoring (2) gives 
$$
   6y(x-2y) = 0
$$
from which we conclude *either* $y=0$ *or* $x=2y$.

In the first case, $y=0$, (1) reduces to 
$$
3x^2 + 2x-33 =0
\implies (x-3)(3x+11) = 0
$$
Therefore x= 3 or $x=-\frac{11}{3}$.
This gives us two critical points, $\left(3,0\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{11}{3},0\right)$.

In the second case, $x=2y$, (1) reduces to
$$
3(2y)^2 + 3y^2 + 2(2y) - 33 = 0
\implies 15y^2 + 4y-33 = 0
$$
The solutions are $y = \frac{1}{15}\left(-2\pm\sqrt{499}\right)$.
This gives two more critical points: $\left(\frac{2}{15}\left(-2+\sqrt{499}\right),\frac{1}{15}\left(-2+\sqrt{499}\right)\right)$, and $\left(\frac{2}{15}\left(-2-\sqrt{499}\right),\frac{1}{15}\left(-2-\sqrt{499}\right)\right)$

See [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolfr.am/7DZREXbb)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ is given by: $f_y=6 y (x-2 y)$

Comment: so if y= 0 or x=2y then the function= 0?

Comment: and use the second equation!

Comment: @spexel: If $y= 0$ or $x=2y$ then $f'_{y}=0,$ not the function $f(x,\,y).$

Comment: If i plug the value $y=0$ and $x=0$ in the other equation i get: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=(6x+11)(2x-3)$, i still don't understand what to do with that.

Comment: no plug $y=0$ or $x=2y$ in the equation $$3x^2+3y^2+2x-33=0$$